# how to using plugin with inherited auth as child of other plugin

Tags: authentication, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.x

for my application i want to write an "admin" plugin, named "db" with own auth-component. To manage acl i tried to implement [**`ivanamat/cakephp3-aclmanager`**](https://github.com/ivanamat/cakephp3-aclmanager) as part of my admin tool, because my app won't need user authentification, maybe later.

i load `AclManager` in `plugins/db/Plugin.php`

```
public function bootstrap(PluginApplicationInterface $app)
{
    Configure::write('AclManager.aros', array('DbGroups', 'DbRoles', 'DbUsers'));
    parent::bootstrap($app);
    $app->addPlugin('AclManager', ['routes' => false]);
}
```

I set up Routing Rules in `db/config/routes.php`

```
Router::connect(
    'db/acl',
    ['plugin' => 'AclManager', 'controller' => 'Acl', 'action' => 'index']
);

Router::connect(
    'db/acl/:action/*',
    ['plugin' => 'AclManager', 'controller' => 'Acl']
);
```

And i set up Auth Configuration in `plugins/db/Controller/AppController.php`

It's loaded and aside a "Auth not found"-error it works, but this is my problem.

When i debug `$this->Auth` in `app.local/db/` it's filled. But not when i debug in `app.local/db/acl`. even when i load this plugin in my plugin, it's using Base `AppController`, not Plugin `AppController`.

Is it possible to inherit auth from plugin to plugin or load plugins with parent-child-association?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change what a (controller) class inherits, that is compile time information, and once it's processed, it is what it is, the controller classes of the `AclManager` plugin do extend `App\AppController`.

There's lots of different ways to solve your problem, one would for example be to dynamically configure the authentication in your application's base `App\AppController` class, rather than in your `Db` plugin's `Db\AppController` class.

You can check the routing information whether it's a request for the `Db` plugin or the `AclManager` plugin, and only load the auth component in that case, something like this:

```php
public function initialize()
{
    if (in_array($this->request->getParam('plugin'), ['Db', 'AclManager'], true)) {
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            // ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

That way the `Db` and `AclManager` plugin controller classes will inherit the authenticaton setup while your main application and possible other plugins are being excluded.

ps. if you're just starting to implement authentication, then I'd strongly suggest that you try the new [**authentication**](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1/en/index.html) and [**authorization**](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/1/en/index.html) plugins, they're much more versatile than the (deprecated) auth component!